# Pandas Multiindex count on levels

Tags: pandas, count, series, multi-index

The data:

```
index = [('A', 'aa', 'aaa'),
         ('A', 'aa', 'aab'),
         ('B', 'bb', 'bbb'),
         ('B', 'bb', 'bbc'),
         ('C', 'cc', 'ccc')
        ]
values = [0.07, 0.04, 0.04, 0.06, 0.07]

s = pd.Series(data=values, index=pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(index))

s
A  aa  aaa    0.07
       aab    0.04
B  bb  bbb    0.04
       bbc    0.06
C  cc  ccc    0.07
```

To get a mean of first two levels is easy:

```
s.mean(level=[0,1])
```

Result:

```
A  aa    0.055
B  bb    0.050
C  cc    0.070
```

But to get a count on first two levels does not work the same:

```
#s.count(level=[0,1]) # does not work
```

I can get around with:

```
s.reset_index().groupby(['level_0', 'level_1']).size()

level_0  level_1
A        aa         2
B        bb         2
C        cc         1
```

But there must be a cleaner way to get the same result? Am I missing something obvious?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems bug, you can use:

```
print (s.groupby(level=[0,1]).size())
#with exclude NaNs
#print (s.groupby(level=[0,1]).count())
A  aa    2
B  bb    2
C  cc    1
dtype: int64
```

Comment: Never thought of Series having a "groupby" method :) this is helpful and I accept the answer as the cleaner way but maybe can anyone confirm that there is no "count method" alternative for speed and efficiency?

Comment: @arvyzu - It seems not yet ;(